# Проблемы с кодировкой в jar

Tags: кодировка, java

Есть метод, который *дописывает* построчно путь к файлу в текстовый файл:

```
    FileWriter fw;
    try {
        fw = new FileWriter(System.getProperty("user.home")+"/VK_MM/aids.txt", true);
        fw.append(aid);
        fw.append(System.getProperty("line.separator")); //переходим на новую строку
        fw.flush();
        fw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Есть метод, который потом считывает оттуда:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((new FileInputStream(aids)), "UTF-8"));
```

И видимо какой-то из этих методов портит файл, видимо 1 метод с неправильной кодировкой записывает в файл, причем неправильно он это делает, когда запускаешь runnable jar. В эклипсе же все нормально. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы пишете в файл в одной кодировке, а читаете в юникоде. Тогда и пишите в юникоде, когда создаете FileWriter.

Comment: А как указать FileWriter в какой писать кодировке? Ничего путного не нашел.

Comment: Ищите, можно обернуть в BufferedWriter, наверное.

Comment: Точнее в OutputStreamWriter

Comment: Или читайте файл так же как пишете, с помощью FileReader, выбор за вами

Comment: С OutputStreamWriter у меня проблема с дописыванием. FW дописывает, а OSW стирает и пишет

Comment: А вообще, я убрал везде упоминание кодировок. Пока что проблемы с кодировкой не наблюдаются, посмотрим, что будет.